# What's the best practice way to test block Views with SImpleTest?

Tags: views, features, testing

I've created a block view, which I've positioned on the  page using the admin UI. I've exported my view using Features and fe_block for its block.

I'd like to write a SimpleTest to verify that content from the view is displaying on the front page.

I've written a test that creates some nodes (of the type being displayed by the view), then does a drupalGet('/') and some assertText() statements to verify the content is displayed.

However, these are currently failing. When I view the HTML of the frontpage as seen by SimpleTest, the view isn't there.

Have I missed something? Is there a better way to be testing this?

Answer (score 0):

The simpletest code needs to place the block into a region. Then, you should see the content after doing the drupalGet('/').

Comment: The block positioning is already specified in the feature exported by fe_block